# How to know which version of openssl boost ssl is using

Tags: c++, openssl, boost-asio

I have some questions about boost openssl updation

1. How can I find out which version of openssl boost ssl is using?
2. Do we need to recompile the C++ boost application after updating openssl or will updating openssl suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Boost will use the openssl version provided by your system (or explicitly specified during compilation/linkage, check your build script)
2. It depends on your linkage type, if you link statically against OpenSSL, you will need to recompile. If you are linking dynamically, then updating the DLL/shared object will be enough (unless you linked against a specific version)

Comment: *If you are linking dynamically, then updating the DLL/shared object will be enough (unless you linked against a specific version)*. AFAIK OpenSSL 1.1.0 is not binary compatible with 1.0.2